# Which one is better - calculate object field with deep population OR calculate field when saving object and update it when necessary?

Tags: database, mongodb, data-structures, apollo-server, population

I'm trying to structure my database and backend in a way that would need the less amount of calculation and queries when one object updates. I'm using Apollo-server, Mongoose and MongoDB.

I have

`FoodPack MANY---MANY Food`

`Food MANY---MANY Ingredient`

Every object there has a `kcal` property. Right now if I make query allFoodPacks I need to populate all Foods and within Foods all Ingredients so I can calculate a FoodPack's `kcal` column.

I made the structure like so because when I update one Ingredient's `kcal`, I don't need to update every Food and FoodPack fields too, as they get calculated with the queries with population.

ANOTHER solution would be to calculate the FoodPack's `kcal` during creation of the FoodPack object. That way querying FoodPack and it's `kcal` column wouldn't need deep population, BUT if Ingredient's `kcal` in the FoodPack's Foods would change, I would need to update all the objects that reference that Ingredient.

Which one would be better solution, assuming the app has decent amount of users?

Comment: Largely a matter of opinion, but give some thought to how much processing you'd have to do in each case. Updating every Food and FoodPack that contains a common ingredient will take a very long time. Calculating a FoodPack's kcal, on the other hand, only involves querying a few Food and Ingredient records. Which query do you think will take less time?

Comment: Thank you for the perspective. I came to the conclusion that it's going to take a lot more queries if I would have to change every instance of Ingredient in Foods and Foodpacks (as opposed to only three queries with deep population when quering all FoodPacks, their Foods their Ingredients). So calculating the field is definitely better.